# In PyQt6 or PySide6, is it possible to do alignment with CSS stylesheet?

Tags: css, alignment, pyside6, pyqt6

In PyQt6 or PySide6, is it possible to do alignment with CSS only ?

For example to align a text label in code, we do :

```
self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignTop)
```

Can we do the same thing in a stylesheet?

I think I read in some book one could do :

```
self.label_1.setStyleSheet('qproperty-alignment: AlignRight;')
```

but it does not work.

Comment: @Alexander actually, that's completely false. Not only it works for QLabel, but the mechanism works just like any writable Qt property. The only problem is that Qt6 doesn't seem to recognize enum flags as it did for Qt5.

Comment: @u2gilles Use `self.label_1.setStyleSheet(f'QLabel {{ qproperty-alignment: {int(AlignRight)}; }}')`. Note the [class selector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types): it doesn't really matter if you specifically set the stylesheet on the label, properties are specific to objects, and you should not set them "globally".

Comment: yes, it answed the question

Comment: As type(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight) is a python enum in PyQt6 (not in PySide6), 'qproperty-alignment: {Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight};' also works. But 'int(AlignRight)' works in both variants, so I'll keep this one. Thanks again musicamante